# Elementor builder issue

Tags: wordpress, mobile, elementor

I'm having trouble setting up my website in the Elementor Wordpress builder. When editing a page in Elementor, I'm currently optimizing the website for mobile phones. However, unfortunately, I must have accidentally set something in the past that is now causing me trouble. When I open the website on my phone, there's an option to zoom in, and then I see a wide, long white space on the right side. It's as if I must have set something in the past, perhaps in the page settings, to have that space there. This has never happened to me before.

[Mobile website screenshot with issue on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPvlk.jpg)

I would need advice on how to disable this setting and remove the white vertical space.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.